# How to create MySQL table with Foreign key and Unique key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table, unique-key

I'm trying to create the second table of my database, but I am running into several errors. This is in MySQL on my Ubuntu system.

```
CREATE TABLE `Database_Name`.`Table_Name`(
   `Col_One` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Col_Two` INT NOT NULL,
   `Col_Three` LONGTEXT NULL,
   `Col_Four` LONGTEXT NULL,
   `Col_Five` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Col_One`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`Col_Two`) REFERENCES `First_Table` (`First_Table_Info`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   UNIQUE KEY (`Col_Two`, `Col_One`));
```

It is giving me Error 1064 and Error 1170.

The SQL runs fine without the FOREIGN KEY and UNIQUE KEY lines at the bottom, so those are the lines that I believe are causing trouble.

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
CREATE TABLE `Database_Name`.`Table_Name`(
`Col_One` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Col_Two` INT NOT NULL,
`Col_Three` LONGTEXT NULL,
`Col_Four` LONGTEXT NULL,
`Col_Five` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Col_One`),
FOREIGN KEY (`Col_Two`) REFERENCES `First_Table` (`First_Table_Info`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
UNIQUE KEY (`Col_Two`, `Col_One`));
```

ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `Database_Name`.`Table_Name`(
`Col_One` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Col_Two` INT NOT NULL,
`Col_Three` LONGTEXT NULL,
`Col_Four` LONGTEXT NULL,
`Col_Five` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Col_One`),
FOREIGN KEY (`Col_Two`) REFERENCES `First_Table` (`First_Table_Info`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
UNIQUE KEY (`Col_Two`, `Col_One`));
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error messages. With each error number there probably is a line of text explaining the problem.

Comment: Error 1170 seemed to have disappeared after getting rid of an unnecessary comma or something...

Comment: 1064 and 1046 have nothing to do with FKs.

Comment: still doesn't work regardless

Comment: Read & act on [mcve].